# I am given positive integers $1,2,3,...,4k$.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, factorial

I am given a list of positive integers $1,2,3,...,4k$.

Let integer $n$ be the median of 3 randomly picked integers from the list.

What would be the exact probability that $k\leq n-1\leq 3k$?

Comment: Why introduce $t$ at all.  It is just $n-1$

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, sorry it should just be n-1.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @l1mbo I have found that if k=1, probability is 1. If k=2, probability is 44/56. If k=3, probability is 82/220. However I'm struggling to figure out the pattern that exist here. I feel like it will involve using factorials though.

Comment: Did you not understand my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle number of the three shall be the median. So, for the median $n$ to satisfy $k+1\leq n\leq 3k+1$, it means that at least one number is choosen from this partition of the set (let's call this subset $S$, $n<k+1$ as $A$ and $n>3k+1$ as $B$), and for that number to be the median we can have three cases:

**Case 1:** All three numbers are chosen from $S$

**Case 2:** Two numbers chosen from $S$, one from $A$

**Case 3:** Two numbers chosen from $S$, one from $B$

**Case 4:** One number is chosen from $S$, one from $A$, one from $B$

I believe the thinking part of the problem is done now, the rest should be relatively straightforward combinatorics